# Replacing char* with shared_ptr<char>

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr

I have a struct as follows:

```
struct P
{
    enum {INT, FLOAT, BOOLEAN, STRING, ERROR} tag;
    union
    {
        int a;
        float b;
        bool c;
        const char* d;
    };
};
```

I'm using cereal library to serialize this and cereal does not support raw pointers. I'm replacing `const char* d` with `const shared_ptr<char> d`. I'm facing 3 issues:

1. Converting char* to shared_ptr:

   ```
   char* x = //first element of char array
   d = shared_ptr<char> (x); // is this the right way?
   ```
2. Handling assignments like:

   ```
   string s = "hello";
   d = s.c_str(); // how to convert the c_str() to shared_ptr<char>?
   ```
3. From what I've read, shared_ptr seems to handle pointers very different from raw pointers. Will I be able to use this shared_ptr as a character array safely without any side effects?

Comment: It looks like your raw pointers are non-owning, so you'll likely double-delete something. Is there another option for your library other than using `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: do you suggest using unique_ptr instead? I'm using shared_ptr since it doesn't cause ownership conflicts.

Comment: Can you use `std::shared_ptr <std::string>`? Unless you're trying to serialize a character, `std::shared_ptr <char>` won't work. Maybe `std::shared_ptr <char[]> `?

Comment: 1. It's wrong way; 2. It's hasn't to do this

Comment: Maybe you could use a `std::shared_ptr` with a custom no-op deleter?

Comment: What does `d` represent? If it's a string, why aren't you using `std::string`? Is it something permanent, like a constant? Who manages the life of whatever `d` points to in your design?

Comment: d represents shared_ptr<char> in the 3 issues. I'm not using string for d since strings aren't allowed to be a member of union. I'm trying to serialize character array pointed to by char* d. Trying your suggestion of using shared_ptr<char[]> now.

Comment: @codeln Do you understand *why* `std::string` can't be used in a union? Because, if you don't, you're going to work around a safety without understanding what the safety protects you from. That would be a very bad idea.

Comment: `String` != `std::string` (C++ is case sensitive).

Comment: answer updated. Please take care to read the preamble and the warnings. Then enjoy the complexity of discriminated unions in c++. Then please, please, for your own sake, use a `boost::variant` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to say is that you're using a union. Unions in c++ are *really* hard to get right. Do you really need a union?

If you *really* need a union, use `boost::variant` instead. It solves all the complexity for you.

Next, we're using C++ - not C. Let's act like it. Get rid of that const char *. It's a landmine. That's why cereal does not support it. They're doing the right thing. Replace it with what it is. A `std::string`.

EDIT:

OK. You asked for it. Here is a solution using a discriminated union.

Now, remember I said that unions are *hard* to get right in c++?

I've been writing c++ almost every day for the past 15 (20?) years. I'm an avid follower of the progress of the standard, I always use the latest tools and I demand that people in my team know the language and the standard library inside out... and I am not yet sure that this solution is fully robust. I would need to spend a day writing tests to be *really* sure... because discriminated unions are *really hard* to get right.

EDIT2:

fixed the 'construct from const char*' bug (told you it was hard...)

Are you *sure* you would rather not use `boost::variant`?

No? ok then:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct error_type {};
static constexpr error_type as_error = error_type {};

struct P
{
    enum {
        INT, FLOAT, BOOLEAN, STRING, ERROR
    } _tag;

    union data
    {
        data() {}
        ~data() {} // define a destructor that does nothing. We need to handle destruction cleanly in P

        int a;
        double b;   // use doubles - all calculation are performed using doubles anyway
        bool c = false;  // provide a default constructor
        std::string d;  // string or error
    } _data;

    // default constructor - we must initialised the union and the tag.

    P() : _tag { BOOLEAN }, _data {} {};

    // offer constructors in terms of the various data types we're storing. We'll need to descriminate
    // between strings and errors...

    P(int a) : _tag (INT) {
        _data.a = a;
    }

    P(double b) : _tag (FLOAT) {
        _data.b = b;
    }

    P(bool c) : _tag (BOOLEAN) {
        _data.c = c;
    }

    P(std::string s) : _tag(STRING)
    {
        new (std::addressof(_data.d)) std::string(std::move(s));
    }

    // provide a const char* constructor... because const char* converts to bool
    // more readily than it does to std::string (!!!)
    P(const char* s) : P(std::string(s)) {}

    P(std::string s, error_type) : _tag(ERROR)
    {
        new (std::addressof(_data.d)) std::string(std::move(s));
    }

    // destructor - we *must* handle the case where the union contains a string
    ~P() {
        destruct();
    }

    // copy constructor - we must initialise the union correctly

    P(const P& r)
    : _tag(r._tag)
    {
        copy_construct(r._data);
    }

    // move constructor - this will be particularly useful later...

    P(P&& r) noexcept
    : _tag(r._tag)
    {
        steal_construct(std::move(r._data));
    }

    // assignment operator in terms of constructor
    P& operator=(const P& p)
    {
        // this line can throw
        P tmp(p);

        // but these lines will not
        destruct();
        steal_construct(std::move(tmp._data));
        return *this;
    }

    // move-assignment in terms of noexcept functions. Therefore noexcept
    P& operator==(P&& r) noexcept
    {
        destruct();
        _tag = r._tag;
        steal_construct(std::move(r._data));
        return *this;
    }

    // don't define swap - we have a nothrow move-assignment operator and a nothrow
    // move constructor so std::swap will be optimal.

private:

    // destruct our union, using our tag as the type switch
    void destruct() noexcept
    {
        using namespace std;
        switch (_tag) {
            case STRING:
            case ERROR:
                _data.d.~string();
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    /// construct our union from another union based on our tag
    void steal_construct(data&& rd) noexcept
    {
        switch(_tag) {
            case INT:
                _data.a = rd.a;
                break;
            case FLOAT:
                _data.b = rd.b;
                break;
            case BOOLEAN:
                _data.c = rd.c;
                break;
            case STRING:
            case ERROR:
                new (std::addressof(_data.d)) std::string(std::move(rd.d));
                break;
        }
    }

    // copy the other union's data based on our tag. This can throw.
    void copy_construct(const data& rd)
    {
        switch(_tag) {
            case INT:
                _data.a = rd.a;
                break;
            case FLOAT:
                _data.b = rd.b;
                break;
            case BOOLEAN:
                _data.c = rd.c;
                break;
            case STRING:
            case ERROR:
                new (std::addressof(_data.d)) std::string(rd.d);
                break;
        }
    }

public:

    // finally, now all that union boilerplate malarkey is dealt with, we can add some functionality...

    std::string report() const {
        using namespace std::string_literals;
        using std::to_string;

        switch (_tag)
        {
            case INT:
                return "I am an int: "s + to_string(_data.a);
            case FLOAT:
                return "I am a float: "s + to_string(_data.b);
            case BOOLEAN:
                return "I am a boolean: "s + (_data.c ? "true"s : "false"s);
            case STRING:
                return "I am a string: "s + _data.d;
            case ERROR:
                return "I am an error: "s + _data.d;
        }
    }


};

int main()
{
    P p;
    std::cout << "p is " << p.report() << std::endl;

    auto x = P("hello");
    std::cout << "x is " << x.report() << std::endl;

    auto y = P("goodbye", as_error);
    std::cout << "y is " << y.report() << std::endl;

    auto z = P(4.4);
    std::cout << "z is " << z.report() << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

expected results:

```
p is I am a boolean: false
x is I am a string: hello
y is I am an error: goodbye
z is I am a float: 4.400000
```

Comment: This makes a lot more sense, thanks for pointing out the right way of using a  string in a tagged union.

Comment: This still gives: `error: union member ‘P::<anonymous union>::d’ with non-trivial ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’
         std::string d;`
I'm using g++ -std=C++0x, yet this error arises

Comment: Also states that the struct definition is ill formed. I've added constructors and destructor properly. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Like I said, unions are hard. I'm driving from Madrid to Barcelona now but can revisit this evening if you can wait.

Comment: Sure, appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `char *` with `shared_ptr<char>`, as requested by the question title, can be made to compile (with the help of a custom deleter), but it's almost never useful, and will almost certainly not do the right thing in the context of cereal. Since cereal understands standard library types such as strings, why not just use them directly?

Since unions and non-POD types don't really mix, as aptly demonstrated by Richard, you can convert the union into inherited classes with a virtual member function to discriminate the type:

```
struct P {
  enum tag_type {INT, FLOAT, BOOLEAN, STRING, ERROR };
  virtual tag_type get_tag() const = 0;
  // allow subclsas deletion through base class pointer
  virtual ~P() {}
};
struct PInt: public P {
  tag_type get_tag() { return INT; }
  int a;
};
struct PFloat: public P {
  tag_type get_tag() { return FLOAT; }
  float b;
};
struct PBool: public P {
  tag_type get_tag() { return BOOL; }
  bool c;
};
struct PStr: public P {
  tag_type get_tag() { return STRING; }
  std::string d;
};
struct PError: public P {
  tag_type get_tag() { return ERROR; }
};
```

The code you will end up with is still clunky, but it will handle non-PODs easily and robustly. Using it would boil down to replacing old code that looked like this:

```
void process(P& x)
  switch (x.tag) {
    case INT:
      // use x._data.a
      ...
  }
}
```

...with code that uses the `get_tag()` virtual member to get the tag, and `dynamic_cast` to access the attributes of the final class:

```
void process(P& x)
{
  switch (x.get_tag()) {
    case P::INT:
      PInt &intx = dynamic_cast<PInt&>(x);
      // ...use intx.a
    // case P::FLOAT, etc.
  }
}
```

With this setup, you can use [`CEREAL_REGISTER_TYPE(Pint)`](http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/polymorphism.html), to declare your subclasses to cereal. The library will then use run-time type information to correctly serialize pointers to `P`.